# Calling Parent Component function when child component finished loading in knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can I notify Parent Component that a child component has finished loading (it has reached in active state as per [component lifecycle](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html).

I want to do something like this:

```
<parentComponent>
    <!-- Some other html code here -->
    <childComponent>
    </childComponent>
</parentComponent>

parentViewModel = function(params){
    var self = this;
    self.toBeCalledByChild = function() { //Code here }
}
childViewModel = function(params){
    //some code
    parentViewModel.toBeCalledByChild(); //this is to be called when child Component finishes loading
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Knockout Provides several methods to track changes,custom bindings, subscriptions and computed observables for your case I would probably use subscriptions, if you wanted to avoid direct references to observables then you can use decoupled communication, to subscribe to changes there's a beforeChange as well

[Using KO’s Native PubSub for Decoupled Synchronization](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html)